# SWIFT - SpriteKit - SKMetalLayer Warning

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2, xcode7

I am creating a game using sprite kit and Xcode 7.3 in swift. I have also tried to launch the default project however, I always get a warning. I have been trying to google it but I cannot find any solution. How can I remove the warning below?

```
<SKMetalLayer: 0x13763c450>: calling -display has no effect.
```

Comment: No one will be able to help unless you provide a sample code to reproduce the issue. If this is not an option for you, then you can file a bug report directly to Apple via radar (bugreport.apple.com) though they'll likely be asking for the same sort of information.

Comment: This may be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512849/xcode-error-calling-display-has-no-effect

Comment: Yes thank you .. In the end I came up to that stack and solved my issue